# Storing array object in a multidimentional array element in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have a scenario in which i've to store array object in a array.My Javascript code is

```
var myArray= new Array(5,5);
for(dataIndex in data.data){
   for(myIndex in data.data[dataIndex].myObject){
     var xrow =data.data[dataIndex].myObject[myIndex].row;
     var xcolumn =data.data[dataIndex].myObject[myIndex].column; 
     myarray[xrow][xcolumn] = data.data[dataIndex].myObject[myIndex];  
   }

}
```

but could not store any data object in the array.Can anyone help me out sort this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're coming from PHP, where an array is both a sequence of elements and/or key-value pairs? An array in javascript is *just* a sequence. (Actually, that's not 100% true, but it is for all intents and purposes.) What you want is an *object*. An object is a series of key value pairs. The keys and values can be any object, from a string to an array to a function.

```
var myObj = {};
// or assigning properties up front
var myOtherObj = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 12 };
```

Comment: Can u tell me ow can i declare a multidimentional array say myarray with 5 rows and 3 columns in javascript

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not declaring and setting value for the javascript array.I was able to acheive it by this.

```
var YourArrayHere = new Array();
YourArrayHere.length = [first dimension array length here];
for(var count = 0; count < YourArrayHere.length; count++)
{
  var TempSecondArray = new Array();
  TempSecondArray.length = [sec dimension array length here];
  YourArrayHere[count] = TempSecondArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok got a working demo. Took me a while to figure it out. Was fun. It can be optmized.

EDIT: you don't really need a MAX.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/7B8CK/1/

```
var data = {
    "data":[
        {"myObject":[
                {"row":0, "column":0},
                {"row":0, "column":1},
                {"row":0, "column":2},
             ]


        },
        {
            "myObject":[
                 {"row":1, "column":0},
                 {"row":1, "column":1},
                 {"row":1, "column":2}
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var result = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++)
{
    var temp = new Array();
    var row =  (data.data[i].myObject.length > 0) ? data.data[i].myObject[0].row: null;
    for(var j = 0; j < data.data[i].myObject.length; j++)
    {
        console.log('row: ' + data.data[i].myObject[j].row + ', column: ' + data.data[i].myObject[j].column);
        temp[data.data[i].myObject[j].column] = [data.data[i].myObject[j]];

    }
    if(row != null){ result[row] = temp;}
    console.log(result);
}
console.log('Final:');
console.log(result);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/7B8CK/

I represented data as best as I could to fit your example

```
var MAX_X = 10;
var MAX_Y = 10;
var data = {
    "data":[
        {"myObject":[
                {"row":0, "column":0},
                {"row":0, "column":1},
                {"row":0, "column":2},
             ]


        },
        {
            "myObject":[
                 {"row":1, "column":0},
                 {"row":1, "column":1},
                 {"row":1, "column":2}
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var result = new Array(MAX_X);
for(var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++)
{
    var temp = new Array(MAX_Y);
    var row =  (data.data[i].myObject.length > 0) ? data.data[i].myObject[0].row: null;
    for(var j = 0; j < data.data[i].myObject.length; j++)
    {
        console.log('row: ' + data.data[i].myObject[j].row + ', column: ' + data.data[i].myObject[j].column);
        temp[data.data[i].myObject[j].column] = [data.data[i].myObject[j]];

    }
    if(row != null){ result[row] = temp;}
    console.log(result);
}
console.log('Final:');
console.log(result);
```